# Swiping to navigate through, then load an array of AR assets in iOS

Tags: ios, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am relatively new to Swift.

I am building an application in which I would like to swipe through an array of AR assets; essentially swipe right or left and a new .scn model is rendered and interacts with the scene. However, loadedContentForAssets only takes a value string and inputting a var initiates a search for a model of the same name (that naturally doesn't exist). Any help is greatly appreciated or pointers in the general direction.

Cheers.

P.S.

Here is what I am using to implement the transition so far (`faceOverlayArray` is an array of `SCNNodes`). I would like to allow navigating/swiping to the end and then loop back to the `index 0`. Seeing two errors: 
`Cannot convert value of type '(Any) -> Int' to expected argument type '(UnboundedRange_) -> ()`
and 
`Cannot assign to property: 'index' is a method`.

```
`func didSwipeRight() {
let arrayLength = faceOverlayArray.count
var faceOverlayContent = self.faceOverlayArray[index]
index = (index < faceOverlayArray.count-1) ? index+1 : 0
}`
```

Comment: Please show us the code you have done so far

Comment: Edited the post above*

Comment: How is index defined, and where? Maybe you need prefix it with self?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!